# Where do the abbreviations for standard agglomerative methods come from?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

Considering methods like UPGMA, WPGMA, and WPGMC, etc, I wonder where these abbreviations actually come from.  What is the canonical quote for them where you can look up the origin of the names, etc?

(Please note that I am not looking for an explanation of their mathematical definitions.)